# Как реализовать выпадающий список, как в google play?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Как реализовать выпадающий список, как в google play? На изображении выделил красным маркером.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: PopupMenu, PopupWindow

Comment: Использовал решение вот отсюда http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588781/android-popup-menu-when-list-item-view-pressed